# How to clear the buffer in Code Blocks?

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I am using code blocks and i need a good and easy way to clear the buffer.I am using getch() form the conio.h library for input.

Comment: `fflush(stdout)`? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: hmm doesn t seems to work. Let me be more specific:i have some text outputing on the screen with cout . i use sleep() to make it output slowly. After the output there is getch().What i need is something that will clar the buffer so if I accidentaly imput randomly while the text comes out, the buffer will be cleaned before getch() because after getch I clear the screen.Thx in advance

Comment: What operating system are you using? I infer from the use of `conio.h` that it is some Microsoft OS. Is that correct?

Comment: indeed, is a windows dependent library. And im using windows xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this untested code:

```
// send the data to cout here
...
// clear the console input:
while(_kbhit()) _getch();

// Fetch a single key:
char ch = _getch();
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted.Thanks a lot.Btw i used just while(_kbhit()) _getch(); since i already have the getch() function called after the while loop.Hope you don't mind if i use this code in my program,do you?

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to use that code any way you would like. Please remember to "accept" my answer if it solved your problem. Generally, upvote all useful answers (click on the upward-pointing triangle) and accept the single answer that help the most (click on the check-mark).

Answer (score 0):

u can use fflush(stdin); to clear the stream.